# Ivy.xml and how to configure

Tags: java, ivy

So i just got internship at a firm and there we have to work with java. I have been a C guy all my life but i am familiar with the basic OOP fundamentals. 
Now there is a file `ivy.xml`.

I asked someone what it was and how do i use it and I just got that it resolves all the dependencies in the code. 
Now can someone help me in understanding what it is, what does one mean by the dependency resolution and how do i configure it to my uses?

Maybe a simple example can help understanding more quickly.

Thanks a tonne.

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is a plugin to [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), one of the most popular build tools (a bit like `make` or autotools) for java. There are many ways in which it can be configured, both in that `ivy.xml` file and in the `build.xml` for ant. I'd stick with established practice already used in that firm, i.e. modify the structure of these files as little as possible. To understand the stuff already present, either read [the manuals](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html) or provide file snippets along with specific questions.

Comment: thanks for the link. will go through it.